# React native nested flex

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I am using `react-native-elements`. I am having difficulty in layout system of `react-native`.

```
 <View style={styles.container}>
    {canAccessCamera ? (
        <Card style={styles.userInfo}>
            <Avatar medium source={Logo} rounded />
            <Text>Username</Text>
        </Card>
    ) : (
      <Text>Give me access to camera</Text>
    )}
  </View>
```

Style:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  userInfo: {
    display: 'flex',
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
});
```

I want items inside `Card` located by column not by row.

This is my result:

[image: Here is the result I get]
I want that `Username` stay in the right of the `Avatar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change just this style

```
  userInfo: {
      display: "flex",
      alignItems: "center",
      flexDirection: "row",
      justifyContent: "flex-start"                      
 },
  container:{
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "stretch",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
    paddingTop: 5,
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
    alignItems: "center"
```

Comment: No success it is still the same. [You may want to see my snack](https://snack.expo.io/@bungler/certus-mobile)

Comment: If you want the username to be at the right of the avatar,you should change your styles to this,I did it and it worked.